# Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: anchor, javascript, error, node, failed

I am trying to map the parking space in a location. In the flowing is my account and method to return the available position in a location.

```
#[account]
pub struct Location {
    pub id : String,            // 40 bytes
    pub state_id: u8,           // 1
    pub city_id: u16,           // 2
    // position
    pub top_left : Point,       // 8
    pub bottom_right : Point,   // 8

    pub avaliable_spots: Vec<bool>,

}


impl Location {
   pub fn get_avaliable_spots(&mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
        

        let mut avaliable_spots = Vec::<u8>::new();


        //TODO: CHECK REMOVE PROTECTED CHANELS
        for i in 0..50 {
            if self.spots[i] == false {
                let ui = i as u8;
                avaliable_spots.push(ui + 1);
            }
        }
        avaliable_spots 
        
}
```

I've create this method to return the avaliable spots of one location.

```
pub fn get_avaliable_spots_in_location(ctx: Context<GetSpotsInLocation> ) -> Vec<u8> {

    let location = &mut ctx.accounts.location;
    // Ok(())
    location.get_avaliable_spots()
    
}
```

This is my client code (javascript)

```
async function setAvaliableSpots(program,key_pair,bd_loc_id,spots) {
    let [bc_loc_id, location_bump] = await bcUtil.genLocationPDA(program,bd_loc_id);
    let loc = await program.account.location.fetch(bc_loc_id);
    let spot_list = Uint8Array.from(spots.map(Number))

    console.log(loc) // this is printed

    //rever esse metodo
    let tx = await program.rpc.setSpotsInLocation( spot_list, {
        accounts: {
            creator: key_pair.publicKey,
            location: bc_loc_id,
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        }, 
        signers: [key_pair]
    })
    console.log('tx: ' + tx);
    console.log('---------------');
}
```

when executing the code I get the following error:

```
sendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/workspaces/xxx/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7580:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/workspaces/xxx/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7537:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/workspaces/xxx/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:173:23)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/workspaces/xxx/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:89:20)
    at async Object.rpc [as getAvaliableChannelInLocation] (/workspaces/xxx/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/rpc.js:15:24)
    at async getAvaliableChannels (/workspaces/xxx/board/app/examples/bcChannelLocationQuery.js:56:14) {
  logs: [],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack { stack: [] }
}
```

It is important to mention that my key is valid in the devnet.

```
PublicKey {
  _bn: <BN: b2e38753222e28b686bfddc8927ddb7d73496fd48b2f1bfc4e63194349239195>
}
```

Does any one have an idea how can i fix this error?

PS: My wallet has lampors

root@d7a686c37024:/workspaces/xxx# solana balance
12.65069892 SOL

Comment: What is the cluster you are using in the client code?

Comment: Hello vicyyn, the program are hosted in the devnet.

Comment: I'm talking about the client code. How are you creating your `program` object in your client code?

Comment: Oh sorry,

I get the account ( program.fetch(id) ) and convert the spots to Uint8Array


let spot_list = Uint8Array.from(spots.map(Number))

let tx = await program.rpc.setSpotsInLocation(spot_list, {
        accounts: {
            creator: key_pair.publicKey,
            location: bc_loc_id,
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        }, 
        signers: [key_pair]
    })

Comment: I also update the question with function ( `async function setAvaliableSpots`) in the original post

Comment: I'm once again asking how you initialize the `program` object. before being able to call `program.fetch(id)`. How is `program` **initialized**

Comment: @vicyyn, thank you for the asking that. I was able to find my mistake,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vicyyn ,
Thanks for the help.

It was a mistake in my wallet,I have commented the wrong line of code.

```
let myWallet = new anchor.Wallet(web3js.Keypair.generate());
//let myWallet = new anchor.Wallet(myKeypair);
```

Actually, I was creating a new wallet instead of opening my real wallet(with SOL). When you ask for the initialization of the program I was able to find my mistake.

```
//let myWallet = new anchor.Wallet(web3js.Keypair.generate());
let myWallet = new anchor.Wallet(myKeypair);
```

Once again thank you.